# image disappears after click on javascript

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out why my image goes away after I click.

```
 var GOT = function() {
 document.getElementById("sigil").onclick = function sigilchoice() {
 var name = prompt("who goes there! what is our house name?");
 document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = name;
 return('message');
};
};

GOT();
```

html:

```
 <h1>Choose a King</h1>
 <a href="">
<img id="sigil" src="http://i.imgur.com/sUnMg32.jpg">
 </a>
<p id="message"></p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RznH4/

Comment: @Waymond, can you add all your HTML? that doesn't give me enough information.

Comment: does your Message tag also wraps around the image?

Comment: @̇̇̇NonameBilly Just added! Sorry

Comment: @Waymond that's okay.

Comment: When clicking the image (`#sigil`), the event bubbles to its parent `<a>` and *that* `href` (`""`...which is equivalent to the current page) is followed...so basically, the page just reloads.

Comment: Added JSfiddle for future reference. My fault for not including it in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied and pasted your code into a JSFiddle, but just removed the `<a>` tag, and it seems to work fine without it, with the `<a href="">` it just reloads the page because the `href` is set to: `href=""`

HTML:

```
<h1>Choose a King</h1>
  <img id="sigil" src="http://i.imgur.com/sUnMg32.jpg">
<p id="message"></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("sigil").onclick = function sigilchoice() {
  var name = prompt("who goes there! what is our house name?");
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = name;
  return('message');
};
```

(As you can see same exact code except HTML)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EJaHx/1/)

Comment: Thanks! I added a jsfiddle to the original. lol getting voted down so much.